# How can i check textfield's input is valid Double?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app for simple calculations about e-commerce.
i have some textfield for users to fill.
for instance one of them is shipping price.
if user writes 15 or 15.5 its ok but if user writes 15.5.5 app crashes.
How can i check this and make alert for it.
İ am using Swift and UIKit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your current code so we can see why it crashes

Comment: With answers below, you can do this in willChange delegate method to authorise or not any input.

Answer (score 0):

Do below way

```
var floatString : String = "15.5.5"
print("isFloat==\(floatString.isFloat)")
```

Use extension

```
extension String {
    var isInteger: Bool { return Int(self) != nil }
    var isFloat: Bool { return Float(self) != nil }
    var isDouble: Bool { return Double(self) != nil }
}
```

```
print("15.5.5==\("15.5.5".isFloat)")
print("15.5==\("15.5".isFloat)")
```

Return

```
15.5.5==false
15.5==true
```

So this way you can show alert to user.

```
if (!(yourTextFieldValue.isFloat)) {
    alert("Boss enter valid price")
} else {
    print("valid price--now do what you want")
}
```